# Android : Maintaining several versions of my Android app on Github

Tags: android, git, github, android-studio-3.0

I have already did my first commit of my app on Github. Now I want to maintain several versions (like 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 etc.) of my app, whenever I add a new module to my app, on Github. How to do that using android-studio VCS or using terminal?

Comment: So you want a separate branch for each release of your app? Why? Git already preserves the entire history.

Comment: If I want to discard my newest version for some reason and want to get back to the previous one, then I need the previous version.

Comment: You an easily revert commits.

Answer (score 1):

You can create different branchs for each version. You can have your current version in a generic especific branch and before you change to a new version, create a new branch named after the version of your choice.

If the current version is 1.2, for example, and you need to create a new version, stay in your current branch, create a new branch for version 1.2 and after that return to your current branch. (it will copy all the content of the current branch to a new branch).

To create a branch you can follow this example:

```
git checkout -b v1.2
```

When you go back to the current branch, your new changes will not affect your old version 1.2. It will be safe in it's own branch v1.2.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with **tags**. That's  the correct way to manage versions (or releases) of your app.

The **Git Flow** approach  suggest you start from the master branch, then create a new branch called develop.

> git checkout -b develop

From there you will create a new branch for each feature/request/issue and after it is done,  return to the develop branch.

To create a new branch, if positioning in **develop**

> git checkout -b new-feature

Commit as much as you want in that branch and when done, upload it to GitHub

> git push -u origin new-feature

If the feature is done you can create a Pull Request in GitHub and merge that branch with the develop branch.
Repeat the process until you are ready for a new version/release.

Once you are done create a pull request in GitHub to merge develop into master.
Now the master branch will have all you want for you new version.

To tag it, position on master and update it from GitHub

> git checkout master
>
> git pull origin master

Now your local branch is up-to-date. Let's tag it

> git tag v1.0

An you can also upload the tag to GitHub

> git push --tags

A TAG is a mark in your repository pointing to the code of the specific version/release you have tagged.